# Determine sum of specific elements within an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops, for-loop

I have an array, which stores a series of doubles inputted by the user. The length of the array is the user's choice, and therefore varies. I put the numbers into a loop, which calculates the average and swaps the outlier to the last index of the array. A new average is calculated without the outlier and the new outlier is swapped to the second last index of the array. This cycle is repeated until 1 element remains.

However the outlier is not removed from the array, so I need to calculate the average somehow without the outlier. I was thinking I could specify the index of the elements I want to include in the average.

Comment: If you know the number of values the user has entered, then you have the means to calculate the average.

Comment: While computing average skip the outlier as you already know the number of elements in Array. If you may not be needing outlier again then may be replace it with `0` and compute average normally.

Comment: By outlier you mean minimum element or what? Please clarify.

Comment: element, which is furthest from the average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the process should be like this:

1. Compute average by traversing array till n elements.
2. Find outlier.
3. swap with last element.
4. Now set n to (current size of array - 1). And keep on doing it till size = 0;

I have compiled a code which may work for you. Keep in mind that you may need to make certain small changes as per your requirement.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        double[] dataArray = new double[] {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,7.5,8.5,2.5};
        int arraySizeToConsider = dataArray.length;
        double outlier;
        int index_outlier;
        double avg;
        double diffInOutlierAndAvg;

        while(arraySizeToConsider > 0) {
            outlier = dataArray[0];
            index_outlier = 0;
            avg = computeSum(dataArray,arraySizeToConsider) / (arraySizeToConsider);//avg of elements
            diffInOutlierAndAvg = Math.abs(avg - outlier);

            // find outlier
            for(int index = 0; index<arraySizeToConsider; index++)//increments index
            {
                if(Math.abs(avg - dataArray[index]) > diffInOutlierAndAvg) {
                    outlier = dataArray[index];
                    index_outlier = index;
                }
            }
            double temp = dataArray[arraySizeToConsider -1];
            dataArray[arraySizeToConsider -1] = outlier;
            dataArray[index_outlier] = temp;
            arraySizeToConsider = arraySizeToConsider -1;
            System.out.println("Average: " + avg + " Outlier: " + outlier + " index " + index_outlier + " array size to consider: " +arraySizeToConsider);
        }
    }
    private static double computeSum(double[] array, int arraySizeToConsider) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySizeToConsider; i++) {
            sum = sum + array[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

And here is the output:

`Average: 4.357142857142857 Outlier: 8.5 index 5 array size to consider: 6
Average: 3.6666666666666665 Outlier: 7.5 index 4 array size to consider: 5
Average: 2.9 Outlier: 4.5 index 3 array size to consider: 4
Average: 2.5 Outlier: 1.5 index 0 array size to consider: 3
Average: 2.8333333333333335 Outlier: 3.5 index 2 array size to consider: 2
Average: 2.5 Outlier: 2.5 index 0 array size to consider: 1
Average: 2.5 Outlier: 2.5 index 0 array size to consider: 0`

There are certain improvements which can be made and I have skipped them. That you need to figure out :)

Comment: Given the likelihood this question is derived from a homework problem, do you think this level of detail in your response is warranted?

Comment: Wow. Thank you akhil. My approach is very similar to yours... identical in many cases, but the program never worked. I'm going to analyse your code and see where I went wrong. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is `int size = array.size();` to get the size of the array. I would then use a for loop and loop through the array size - 1 times. For each loop only look at array elements 0 through size - loopCount. The code would look something like this.

```
int size = Array.size();
int outlierLocation;
int sum;
int average;
double temp;
for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
    outlierLocation = 0;
    sum = 0;
    average = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<size-i; i++){
        if (Array[j] is outlier){
            outlierLocation = j;
        }
        sum += Array[j];
    }
    average = sum/(size-i);
    temp = Array(size-i);
    Array[size-i] = Array[outlierLocation];
    Array[outlierLocation] = temp;
}
```

Note: `is outlier` will need to be changed. You did not specify what and outlier was so I put in some filler code. Also the code may need to be changed a bit.